# LRT yielding a test statistic with extreme behavior

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

I have what seems like a textbook binary hypothesis testing scenario: an observation $X$ drawn from one of two probability distributions $\{\Pi_0,\Pi_1\}$ that are known to me, and a need to classify $X$ as having been drawn either according to $\Pi_0$ or $\Pi_1$ (without loss of generality, let's assume equal prior probabilities).  The standard texts on the detection theory (such as Van Trees) prescribe constructing a likelihood ratio test (LRT):

$$\Lambda(X)\triangleq\frac{p_{x|H_1}(X|H_1)}{p_{x|H_0}(X|H_0)}$$

where $H_0$ and $H_1$ denote the hypotheses where $X$ is, respectively, either drawn from $\Pi_0$ or $\Pi_1$.  Since, as I mentioned, both $\Pi_0$ and $\Pi_1$ are known, and the prior probabilities are equal, the likelihood functions $p_{x|H_1}(X|H_1)$ and $p_{x|H_0}(X|H_0)$ are well-defined.  Thus, the test reduces to computing $\Lambda(X)$ and comparing to a threshold.

Denote by $E_0[\Lambda(X)]$ and $E_1[\Lambda(X)]$ the expected value of $\Lambda(X)$ corresponding to, respectively, $X\sim\Pi_0$ and $X\sim\Pi_1$.  Similarly, denote by $\operatorname{Var}_0[\Lambda(X)]$ and $\operatorname{Var}_1[\Lambda(X)]$ the variance of $\Lambda(X)$ corresponding to, respectively, $X\sim\Pi_0$ and $X\sim\Pi_1$.

Now, in my particular scenario, under certain parameters for $\Pi_1$ (and the corresponding likelihood function $p_{x|H_1}(X|H_1)$), I am finding that both $\operatorname{Var}_0[\Lambda(X)]$ and $\operatorname{Var}_1[\Lambda(X)]$ are inifinite.  Furthermore, I am finding that with these parameters the expected value of $\Lambda(X)$ when $X\sim\Pi_1$, $E_1[\Lambda(X)]$, is infinite.

What does this mean?  Per Glen_b's comment, this is not necessarily a trivial detection problem where $\Pi_0$ is always discriminated from $\Pi_1$ without any errors.

So, what can be said (if anything) about the hypothesis test between $H_0$ and $H_1$ based on these facts about $\Lambda(X)$?

Comment: The expectation is not the same as a realization; it doesn't imply that the test is 'trivial' in the sense you indicate.

Comment: Ok, you are right.  However, can we say anything about a test with such properties?  It just seems very strange to me.

Comment: I am sure that many things might be said. If both variances are infinite, the various asymptotic results relating to LRTs are unlikely to hold, for example.

Comment: Hmmm...  that is interesting.  Can you please elaborate on the "various asymptotic results relating to LRTs" that would be unlikely to hold (or, better yet, provide a reference)?  All I really know is the Neyman-Pearson lemma (I come from information theory)...

Comment: I slightly updated the question, hopefully clarifying what I'd like to learn.

Comment: I was thinking of things like Wilks' theorem, but actually on reflection I'm not at all sure I have it right. I'd have to check through the NP lemma and Wilks' theorem carefully.

Comment: The NP lemma still applies. Wilks' theorem won't apply unless the hypotheses are nested. Simulation of the distribution of the LR statistic under the null is likely to be the best option.